# how can insert a system message, and make the bot remember previous conversations

Tags: openai-api, langchain

I'm trying to insert a system message and chat history into this bot but it's either or none
when I change the agent parameter to agent=AgentType.OPENAI_FUNCTIONS and invoke the executor it will listen to the system message, but it won't remember the previous messages and if I kept it as it is it #will not listen to the system message but it will remember previous conversations... is there a way to combine them?

```py
# llm
llm = ChatOpenAI(
    openai_api_key=OpenAI_key,
    model_name='gpt-4'
)

# the retrieval chain
qa = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(
    llm=llm,
    chain_type="stuff",
    retriever=vectorstore.as_retriever()
)

# the memory
conversational_memory = ConversationBufferMemory(
    k=5,
    memory_key="chat_history",
    return_messages=True
)

# the tool that will tell teh llm to use the vector database when it needs to
tools = [
    Tool(
        name="qa-markat",
        func=qa.run,
        description="will answer your question about our website markat and our products",
    )
]

# executing all previous steps
executor = initialize_agent(
    # it's all in this function... if the agent=AgentType.ZERO_SHOT_REACT_DESCRIPTION it will remember but not listen to the system message, but if it
    # was agent=AgentType.OPENAI_FUNCTIONS it will not remember previous conversations but it will listen to the system message
    agent = AgentType.OPENAI_FUNCTIONS,
    tools=tools,
    llm=llm,
    memory=conversational_memory,
    agent_kwargs={"system_message": system_message},
    verbose=False,
    handle_parsing_errors=True
)
```

Comment: "it won't remember the previous messages". what do you mean by previous messages